# PostgreSQL Schema Builder/Diagrams

Tags: postgresql, schema, database-diagrams

I have worked with PostgreSQL, primarily using the Django ORM (started with MySQL and migrated to PostgreSQL) and using pgAdmin for maintenance tasks.

I am now working on an open source project developing an alternative Q&A engine, ( [Codidact.org](https://codidact.org) if anyone is interested). We will be using PostgreSQL but are still working out a lot of details and no ORM has been selected yet.

Can anyone recommend a way to iteratively develop a database structure - tables, fields, FK relationships, etc. - in a way that would make it easy to produce **both**:

- A development (detailed) and/or management (higher level) diagram of the functional components of the database.
- CREATE TABLE commands compatible with PostgreSQL.

The goal is to have a schema definition that effectively generates both human-*useful* (diagram - i.e., not just "read the SQL code") and machine-readable code.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Design_Tools

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have to go through the list myself, but if you have any real-world experience with any of the listed products then please post an answer with the link and the specifics.

Comment: I use the diagram in Navicat for Postgres. It is.....fine. Download trials of several tools and check them out, maybe you'll like one.

Comment: @MorrisdeOryx Thanks - looks like a possibility.

Comment: You could also use the (excellent) MySQL Workbench - generate scripts from that and then run a few `sed` and `awk` scripts on them to convert them to PostgreSQL? There's also the (again excellent) Data Modeller from Oracle - you might be able to take the same approach? You will have to do some "legwork" - but depending on the size of your project, it might be a worthwhile approach. [This](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-database-diagram-tools-available-postgresql) might be of interest? p.s. welcome to the forum! 

Comment: In case anyone arrives here from Google, we ended up using [pgModeler](https://pgmodeler.io/) in Codidact for the time being.